# Scripting a Replication

Tags: sql-server, replication

I don't know too much about SQL Server transactional replication, but am I correct that once we have manually created all the articles we want involved in the replication, we can have that replication 'definition' scripted so that we can either disable the replication or enable it after it's been disable, simply by executing the T-SQL script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right-click on the publication in SSMS, there's a "Generate scripts..." option.  Be careful though: it does some things that while technically correct are non-intuitive and likely to not do what you want.  One that comes to the top of my head is the '@sync_type' parameter to sp_addsubscription.  I've always seen it scripted out as "replication support only" which is likely not what you want.  I guess what I'm trying to say is to review the script before you run it to make sure that it does what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

A simple T-SQL script for creation a publication and its associated subscription:
http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/how-to/create-transactional-replication-tsql-script

An option to deactivate replication is to start/stop replication agents.